# Monitor black but is powered on and fully connected

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, motherboard, linux-mint, hdmi

I have a brand new MSI B450 Gaming Pro Carbon Max (with wifi) (AMD mobo) and a Ryzen 3 CPU, with a brand new MSI 3PA5 monitor, and the VGA and HDMI cords that I've been trying to use have worked via a laptop connection and a previous motherboard. The power works for the case, peripherals, and the monitor, but the screen stays black. I don't have a graphics card, though, and currently am not getting one soon.

I've tried different monitors and different cables, but nothing works.

Question is, am I able to work around this without a graphics card, and if so, how?

Also, it runs on Linux Mint in case that's helpful.

---

Okay, this morning I installed an XHVGA graphics card from 2015 and now the computer won't boot, even though everything is new except the graphics card. I took the graphics card out and it still won't boot.

Comment: Nowadays motherboards do not have graphics chips built-in. The CPU needs to have a graphics chip in order for the onboard video outputs to function. Odds are you don't have one of those AMD CPUs with graphics (please provide/Google the CPU model to confirm).

Comment: I can't remember what the CPU is (it's been a couple years since I first built the computer, and it worked fine up until now) and it's not like I can take it off of the heat sink because of the thermal paste

Comment: I thought you said the motherboard was brand new? But you said it's been a couple years since you first built the computer? Is it a new motherboard of the exact same model or something?

Comment: @SamForbis No, it's a different model. Also, I got it to work, all I needed to do was reseat the CPU and buy some more thermal paste. All good, sorry if this was a waste of time :)